# Prettier doesn't parse Typescript type cast

Tags: typescript, prettier, react-tsx

I'm using Prettier 1.17.1 and TypeScript 3.4.5 with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

I'm getting the error below each time I try to use the `x as T` syntax in TypeScript for type cast:

```
src/Form.tsx
[error] src/Form.tsx: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (82:57)
[error]   80 |                 value={data.position}
[error]   81 |                 onChange={e => {
[error] > 82 |                     const nextPosition = e.target.value as Position
```

I've tried also a different syntax `<T> x` but it breaks TS compilation due to the JSX format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it! I had to explicitly set [the --parser option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#parser) when running it. In the docs, it says that it should be inferred, though it wasn't working for me with `.tsx` files.

`prettier --parser typescript` fixed it

Comment: And how do I set this for eslint-plugin-prettier? 

Already have `parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"` in my `.eslintrc`.

Answer (score 0):

`pietro909`'s comment is correct, but if you're using `.prettierrc` for configuration, you can add this to the file, it would work similarly.

```
  "parser": "typescript"
```